# How to unit test Tag Helper using IHtmlGenerator

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I have created some Tag Helpers in AspNetCore that take IHtmlGenerator generator as  the constructor. I want to create unit tests for these but I don't know what to pass in to the constructors.  I see that the implementation is getting DefaultHtmlGenerator in the constructor but that, in turn, also takes numerous items in the constructor so I'm a little lost on how to do this.

```
public class FormLabelTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public FormLabelTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator)
    {
        this.Generator = generator;
    }

    [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

    public IHtmlGenerator Generator { get; }

    [ViewContext]
    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        TagHelperOutput labelElement = await this.CreateLabelElement(context);
        labelElement.AddClass("control-label", HtmlEncoder.Default);

        output.TagName = null;
        output.Content.AppendHtml(labelElement);
        output.TagMode = TagMode.StartTagAndEndTag;
    }

    protected async Task<TagHelperOutput> CreateLabelElement(TagHelperContext context)
    {
        LabelTagHelper labelTagHelper = new LabelTagHelper(this.Generator)
        {
            For = this.For,
            ViewContext = this.ViewContext
        };

        TagHelperOutput labelOutput = this.CreateTagHelperOutput("label");
        await labelTagHelper.ProcessAsync(context, labelOutput);
        return labelOutput;
    }

    protected TagHelperOutput CreateTagHelperOutput(string tagName)
    {
        return new TagHelperOutput(
            tagName: tagName,
            attributes: new TagHelperAttributeList(),
            getChildContentAsync: (s, t) =>
            {
                return Task.Factory.StartNew<TagHelperContent>(() => new DefaultTagHelperContent());
            });
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you mock `IHtmlGenerator`?

Comment: As already mentioned you could just mock the dependencies to assert the expected behavior of the helpers. With out an actual [mcve], there is not much else we can suggest other than checking some of the examples here https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/master/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.Test

Comment: This looks particularly interesting https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/test/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.Test/TestableHtmlGenerator.cs

Comment: @Nkosi, I did actually find that and attempt to use that but I was getting several build errors that I didn't know how to overcome (no method definition, inaccessible due to protection level). I'm new to unit testing but I didn't think it was as easy as mocking IHtmlGenerator. I'll post my Tag Helper code.